# OSX main queue from console application

Tags: c++, macos, console

I have a c++ console application ported to OSX one of whose dependent libraries depends on running some items on the main queue.

Is there a simple way to accommodate that while remaining a console application (i.e. int main (argc, argv) entry point)? I don't mind doing the console stuff on a separate thread if the entry point thread needs to be doing some kind of processing loop for the queue, although I'd like a way to tell it to quit when I'm done on the other thread.

If that's impossible, are there any simple alternatives? ideally even if it's using a UI framework somehow I will still be doing input/output using the normal console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I really need. The answer is to send the "real" main program off to run on a separate thread using your preferred threading mechanism, and then call `dispatch_main ()` from the `int main ()` entry point. `dispatch_main` never returns so you likely need to call `exit()` on the other thread when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly what it mean to 'run items on the main queue'. It seems like operations related with Foundation/Carbon framework.

The Carbon framework provide C linkage but I have little knowledge about this. If I were you I'll use Objective-C and the Foundation framework way. With Objective-C++ (.mm) you can use almost all C++ functionalities.

In Objective-C code, running the main queue is as simple as below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* mainRL = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
    // run only 10 seconds
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [mainRL runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
        [innerPool release];
    }
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's more complex than I need though. See my own answer below.